# "ERROR: The System Cannot find the file specified" on attempting to load a powershell script via a bat file

Tags: powershell, cmd

TLDR;

I get

```
powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -file "c:\folder\psscript.ps1"
ERROR: the system cannot find the file specified.
```

when I try and call a .ps1 from a bat file, despite the file existing at the quoted location.

---

We are deploying an application whose main requirement was a desktop shortcut users will simply open and do nothing else with (it runs an emergency print job so needs to be quick and no effort).

To this effect, we've built a powershell script which calls a scheduled task on the correct server (calling an application) so it's all preset and ready to go. Our idea was then to just  call this .ps1 in a .bat file which would be launched by a desktop shortcut, awesome, simple. However, whenever we attempt to call the .ps1 we get;

```
ERROR: the system cannot find the file specified.
```

...except the file exists, because a `test-path` comes back as `True` and you can tab complete to the file.

The .bat file's contents are your standard

```
powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -file "c:\folder\psscript.ps1"
```

I've tried providing fully qualified directory paths to powershell.exe, the ps1, and also moving it around various local and network directory paths to see if it makes a difference and... nope.

Opening or running the ps1 directly in powershell works absolutely fine. But we require that 'click and go' from the desktop shortcut. Neutered ps1 script is below (the PW.txt file is accessible by the script);

```
#$key is to decrypt a stored Password for secure credential passing
$key = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24)
$password = get-content "\\full\network\location\PW.txt" | ConvertTo-SecureString -key $key
$securecredentials = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList "domain\adminuser", $password
# Then create a remote session on server job is set up to run on
$session = new-pssession -computername SERVER -credential $securecredentials
Enter-PSSession -Session $session
schtasks /run /TN "Print Job"
#Then to tidy things up we remove sessions and variables from locally run script
Exit-PSSession
Remove-PSSession -ComputerName SERVER
Clear-Variable password
Clear-Variable key
Clear-Variable session
```

Scratching my head at this one, help appreciated!

Comment: Use Procmon to see what file is being searched for and not found.

Comment: That is not a PowerShell error message, so it's most likely produced by something in your PowerShell script. Please show the script content.

Comment: Try the same on a different machine. Or even a different drive. Perhaps its a permission issue.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, edited to show ps1 content. Can you clarify "That is not a PowerShell error message, so it's most likely produced by something in your PowerShell script"? I thought it must be something outside of PowerShell _because_ it's not a PowerShell message.

Comment: @RohinSidharth - tried different machines and locations. Permissions is always my first go-to!

Comment: `Enter-PSSession` is for interactive use. Use `Invoke-Command` instead.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - Understood, I replaced it with enter-pssession as I thought it would provide greater traceability for posting here. It works with ````invoke-command -session $session -scriptblock {schtasks /run /tn "print job"} ````

Comment: @vonPryz suggestion is ALWAYS the answer.  Filter out SUCCESS, the play with other filters until you figure it out.  Again.. NEVER fails.